# To find distance between two letters

Tags: java

In this question,it is required to find the distance between two letters
for eg. Between A and E,the letters are B,C,D.So,distance between the letters is number of letters+1 ie,4 here.But I'm not getting the output for this code

```
     import java.util.*;
     public class Main{
        public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1,s2;
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        input.nextLine();
        s1=input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        s2=input.nextLine();
       int result=((int)s2.toLowerCase().charAt(0)-(int)s1.toLowerCase().charAt(0))+1;
        result=Math.abs(result);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: You have too many input.nextLine() statements in your code (you currently read four lines instead of two). Additionally the +1 is not required.

Comment: First of all you should replace the first and the third nextLine() invocation by next() or just remove it, but remember about additional \n at the end. Then you should remove +1 as @Nevay mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra nextLine method calls. Modified your code to make it working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1, s2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        s1 = input.nextLine();
        s2 = input.nextLine();
        int result = ((int) s2.toLowerCase().charAt(0) - (int) s1.toLowerCase()
                .charAt(0)) + 1;
        result = Math.abs(result);
        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `+1` in the line `int result = ((int) s2.toLowerCase().charAt(0) - (int) s1.toLowerCase().charAt(0)) + 1;` when I remove it it works as expected.

Comment: This is what I am getting :"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)"

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Write 1. character: ");
String s1 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Write 2. character: ");
String s2 = input.nextLine();

String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int s1no = alphabet.indexOf(s1);
int s2no = alphabet.indexOf(s2);

if (s1no > s2no)
 System.out.println("Distance: " + (s1no - s2no));
else
 System.out.println("First character must be bigger than second character");
```